# Вводить-выводить значения

Tags: битрикс

У меня задача написать **модуль для bitrix**, который будет хранить\выводить для каждого пользователя личный список животных пользователя с полями\свойствами.

Мне хотелось бы узнать, с какой стороны подойти к этой задаче.
Подозреваю, что нужно писать модуль, который будет сохранять в базе bitrix животных и полем *id* хозяина (пользователя). При переходе на страницу с карточкой животного запускать проверку на наличие животного у пользователя.

Пролистал документацию (времени читать все нет), но ответа не смог найти. Я, конечно, могу напрямую сделать запись в базу и выборку, но чувствую, что это совсем неправильно.

*P.S. Сделал криво вывод животных из инфоблока, собираюсь сделать добавление через форму, но непонятно, как тогда "раздавать права", т.е. выдавать нужный список животных нужному пользователю.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходимо к инфоблоку животных добавить еще одно свойство. Заходим Контент-инфоблоки-типы инфоблоков. Выбираем ваш инфоблок для животных, переходим на вкладку свойства и вписываем еще одно свойство "Владелец". Тип свойства - привязка к пользователю. Теперь, если правильно будете создавать элементы инфоблока, то можно будет указывать при создании юзера, которому животные принадлежат. Конечно, в этом случае мы можем привязываться только к зарегистрированным пользователям.

Comment: Да, похоже, это правильный подход. Попробую реализовать, спасибо за помощью.